# Disable multiple downloads notification in chrome using Selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium web drive with Chromedriver in order to develop and run UI tests. In one of my tests I am downloading two images and compare them during the tests. Knowing that chrome is going to notify me about trying to download more than one file, I've added this line to the driver initialization function:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
.
.
.
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*,*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1);
```

This has worked for me until today, when I upgraded chrome to version 46.0.2490.71. As from today, the message pops up again, failing my tests.

This is the pop up chrome is giving me:

[image]

I tried to upgrade to the latest webdriver and latest chromedriver but it didn't help.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Change your options statement from:

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*,*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1);
```

to:

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
```

Works for me on Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m.